# Tkinter toplevel loop

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-3.5, toplevel

I have this script where I want to choose image from directory using Tkinter and then choose pixel on it but looks like tkinter.mainloop() never ends. Please help

```
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def callback(event):
    print("Starting pixel of object is: ", event.x, event.y)
    global ps
    ps[0] = event.x
    ps[1] = event.y
    return event.x, event.y


tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
image = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
ps = [0, 0]
window = tkinter.Toplevel()
img = Image.open(image)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=img.size[0], height=img.size[1])
canvas.pack()
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas.create_image(img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] // 2, image=image_tk)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
tkinter.mainloop()
print(ps)
```

Comment: it is normal in all GUI - mainloop has to work till you close window. It gets events from system, sends events to widgets, change widgets, redraw everything - and all in loop. And you have to learn how to live with this ;)

Comment: you have to print it inside `callback` or you have to close window.

Comment: I know but the problem is after I closed the window it is still in that loop 'cause last line isn't printed. I think I messed up a little with tkinter.Tk() and tkinter.Toplevel() so it's not working properly

Comment: now I see you are right - you close only `Toplevel` window but `Tk()` still works - you have to assign `Tk()` to variable - ie. `root` so you could do `root.destroy()` . You can add Button with `command=other_callback` to assign function which will do `window.destroy()` and `root.destroy()`

Comment: or instead of creating `Toplevel` window use `root.deiconify()` to show back `Tk()` and put all inside this window

Comment: or use Label to display it inside window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `deiconify()` to show back `Tk()` window and use it instead of `Toplevel()`

BTW: callback doesn't have to return value because there is nobody to receive this value.

```
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def callback(event):
    global ps # at the beginning to make it more readable

    print("Starting pixel of object is: ", event.x, event.y)
    ps[0] = event.x
    ps[1] = event.y

# --- main ---

ps = [0, 0]

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

image = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

img = Image.open(image)
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root.deiconify() # <-- show `root` again

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=img.size[0], height=img.size[1])
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] // 2, image=image_tk)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

tkinter.mainloop()

print(ps)
```

BTW: you can use Label to display it

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def callback(event):
    global ps

    print("Starting pixel of object is: ", event.x, event.y)
    ps[0] = event.x
    ps[1] = event.y

    label['text'] = str(ps)

# --- main ---

ps = [0, 0]

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

image = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

img = Image.open(image)
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root.deiconify()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=img.size[0], height=img.size[1])
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] // 2, image=image_tk)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

label = tkinter.Label(root)
label.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()

print(ps)
```

[image]

Comment: In some environments `root.deiconify()` may need to be called right after `root.iconify()` in order to make `root` visible again.